# JSF page navigation failing with NullPointerException

Tags: jsf

I wrote two pages...one a form where data submitted and second just to confirm the transaction actually carried out some calculation.

I have a managed bean i.e. FormDataBean and a class Reservation.java from which i instantiate for each booking made. Now I have at the end of a form a submit button:

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="confirmation"/>
```

in the bean I have setters and getters as usual. in a method i defined I create an instance of Reservation, then set the beans variables to the instance variabels, like

```
reservation.startDate = startDate;
reservation.endDate = endDate;
reservation.checkRange();
```

The last method, i.e. checkRange() will use the assigned values to instance variables to carry calculation. it should return a string successful or failure.

Now when I enter data in the form, and press submit, it just refreshes the page but nothing is submitted. because it doesn't go to next page :(
Any idea what is happening? I don't need to define a navigation rule, because in other project, I carry out simple calculation and display result in next page and it worsks! Please advice 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing to tell us some of the more important details so the answer is a kind of guesswork.

As you don't use navigation rules I assume you are using JSF 2, aren't you?

With JSF 2 you can directly set the new navigation target, without navigation rules. A forward to "confirmation" should work if your outcome file is named confirmation.xhtml. Check that. With a navigation rule you could forward it do a different file.

This part should work regardless of the rest.

For the bean not getting any values make sure that you are using the correct scope either through annotation or entry in your faces-config.xml. As you have a quite unusal validation mechanism you probably have to use the session scope.

The correct way would be using an actionlistener that does your checks and then sets the navigation depending on your checks. The bean scope could be more restrictive then.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try action="confirmation?faces-redirect=true"?